# Remove inline style attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

I have a form which uses the values from a select menu to display further select menus depending on the option value.

```
<label for="range">Please select range</label>
<select class="select" name="range" id="range" onChange="showStyles()" selected="">
    <option value="">Select a range</option>
    <option value="gloss">gloss</option>
    <option value="matt">matt</option>
    <option value="wood">wood</option>
    <option value="shaker">shaker</option>
</select>

<div id="styles">
    <label for="style">Which style would you like?</label>
    <select name="gloss" id="gloss" style="display:none;">
        <option value="1" selected="">laminate</option>
        <option value="2" selected="">glass</option>
        <option value="3" selected="">lacquer</option>
    </select> 

    <select name="matt" id="matt" style="display:none;">
        <option value="5" selected="">laminate</option>
        <option value="6" selected="">glass</option>
        <option value="7" selected="">lacquer</option>
        <option value="8" selected="">satin lacquer</option>
        </select> 

    <select name="wood" id="wood" style="display:none;">
        <option value="9" selected="">veneer solid</option>
        <option value="10" selected="">painted solid</option>
        <option value="11" selected="">high gloss veneer</option>
        <option value="12" selected="">laminate</option>
    </select> 

    <select name="shaker" id="shaker" style="display:none;">
        <option value="13" selected="">country shaker</option>
    </select>
```

Each of the subsequent selects is set to display:none and I then have a javascript function to show the appropriate select menu. This isn't working. From the console log I can see that the correct id of the option is being selected but the function is not removing the inline style and displaying the select menu.

```
    //show styles when range is chosen
    function showStyles(){
        var selectedRange = document.getElementById("range").value;
        jQuery('#styles').show();
        jQuery('#'+selectedRange).show('fast');
        console.log(selectedRange);
    }
```

The #styles div is displaying but not the selects.

I have tried to remove the style attribute altogether using:

```
    jQuery('#'+selectedRange).removeAttr( "style" )
```

And also setting a css style using:

```
    jQuery('#'+selectedRange).css("display", "block");
```

But neither are working.

Comment: It works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/Lywb20t2/). Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Also, `jQuery('#'+selectedRange).removeAttr( "title" )` would remove the `title` attribute not the `style`

Comment: Sorry that was a copy and paste error!